# How to embed a C# User Control into Windows Explorer?

Tags: c#, c++

Is it a way to embed my User Control into Windows Explorer? Please tell me if you have any resources about this.

Thanks,
Weipeng

Comment: which type of control you have to Embed?

Comment: You want to create a shell extension? Try this as a start point http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dateparser.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188741.aspx

Answer (score 1):

While you can, and there are a number of examples of how to do this.  I recommend that you do NOT create shell extensions in managed code.

There are a number of reasons for this.  For example, you now have to pull the entire managed runtime into the shell namespace.  This means your explorer instance will use a lot more memory than is necessary.

However, the single biggest reason is that you cannot control which version of the namespace might already be in the shell process space when your control is loaded.  See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx) for why it's a bad idea.

Comment: this is no longer an issue with .NET 4.0. Anyway C++ is for sure the better option.

Comment: @Snoopy - First, the asker did not say they were using .NET 4, and second how do you know for sure?